# auto resize of Loader and loaded SWF

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

is there a way to set the loaded SWF's height and width to always use 100% of the Loader's height and width? pretty much like when you're embedding a swf to an HTML page... I know that you can do this by setting the width and height of the Loader on every stage resize, but is there another way wherein you can just specify height and width is 100% and then loaded SWF will automatically resize according to stage and Loader's current dimensions?

try loaded a SWF file which has coordinates based listeners and it seems that the loaded SWF doesn't reposition its listeners correctly even if the stage is already resized... take this swf for example http://www.mofunzone.com/online_games/the_simple_game.shtml, i tried using an SWFLoader in flex which scales the content and also a normal AS3 flash.display.Loader and it seems that both fails to reposition the listeners correctly. Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

Of cause you don't need to resize automatically, you may set `width=100%` and `height=100%`. Look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS4B441C24-BAE3-4110-91FD-A4E5EEFB2467.html) for example.

Comment: I think you've missed the key part of the question, a **Loader** is being used to display the SWF within another SWF, and the inner SWF needs to be 100% vertically and horizontally.

Comment: yes, this is about the SWF loaded within a SWF element called Loader, which can be used within an HTML file or whatever, the main reason why i need the Loader is to be able to add functionality to ANY swf before embedding them to a HTML page

Comment: seems that this could also be a problem of the loaded SWF since listeners can be added in different ways, the problem is that if it is coordinates based then i guess the SWF must be flexible enough to adjust its positions when the container changes size

but just one question, is the loaded SWF within the Loader even aware when the stage changes its size? hmmmm seems so but i just hope that i can somehow set the loader's width and height before loading a SWF file just like how it is when embedding a swf in a html file

Comment: @user790316, I worked on flash App. We embed loader into html page with swfobject (width and height were 100%), and there was no problem with size after loading app on the current stage.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to specifically set the Loader to size your loaded swf upon completion of a load.

If you always want your loaded swf to be 100% of the stage's width and height, you WOULD need to do a stage resize listener and resize it inside the event handler. If you want it to initialize at 100%, you could do the following inside the **loaded swf**:

```
import flash.events.Event

addEventListener (Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

function onAddedToStage (e:Event):void{
    removeEventListener (Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage)
    this.width = stage.stageWidth;
    this.height = stage.stageHeight;
}
```